# ffmediaplayer playing but screen keeps black

Tags: ffmpeg

I#m coding a video tool for sports with the Windows Template Studio and using the Community Toolkit.MVVM. I finished this with the vlcMediaPlayer and it worked almost fine. I need the Frameback (vlc does not provide) and I like autohiding the controls (which is hard with vlc). So I decided to use the ffmediaelemrnt instead.
Almost everything is ok (I hear sound, i can pause, forward ..), only the Video is not showing!!

I'm using an observable property

```
`    [ObservableProperty]
     private MediaElement _ffmeMediaElement;`
```

instead of the original implementation with a complete different basemodel:

```
public MediaElement MediaElement
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_MediaElement == null)
                    m_MediaElement = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow)?.Media;

                return m_MediaElement;
            }
        }
```

--> Could this be the problem? How do I get the (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow)? in my case with no mainwindow and a page instead

```
                    <ffme:MediaElement
                    x:Name="FfmeMediaElement"
                    Background="Gray"
                    IsDesignPreviewEnabled="True"
                    LoadedBehavior="Play"
                    UnloadedBehavior="Manual" />
</Page>
```

**What I tried**
When I use a contentcontrol instead: the Video is showing, but the controls are not autohiding anymore

When I compile your WindowsSample, it works completly, but still shows the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on <ffme:MediaElement Name="Media" Background="Black" LoadedBehavior="Play" IsDesignPreviewEnabled="True" />

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Everything solved now via ContentControl